# Macro for Inputting info from one workbook to another in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am confused as to how to create a macro for the following process :

There are two workbooks.. one with part numbers (wb1) and the other with part numbers and prices for those numbers (wb2); I need to do the following :

- Find the corresponding part number of wb2 in wb1 and input the price accompanying the part number in wb2 in column k of wb1... however, wb2 has duplicate part numbers and therefore some parts have more than one price.. I need the highest price inputted in column k of wb1 for the correct part number. 
  Additionally, wb1 may have duplicates, but I want the highest price value from wb2 for the correct part number to be inputted in all duplicates of the part number in wb1
  Here is a visual : 
  [image: VISUAL]

Hopefully this made sense, let me know how I can accomplish this!

Comment: You maybe don't need VBA for this. You could use `Lookup` functions `INDEX` and `MATCH`. In any event you should try to visually represent the layout and hoped for result.

Comment: @DougGlancy I have included a visual... let me know if it makes it easier

Comment: Will the duplicates **always** fall sequentially like that?

Comment: As a side note, don't forget to accept answers (to past and present questions) that have worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a setup like this:

[image]

You can use a formula like this:

```
=MAX(IF([Book1]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8=A2,[Book1]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8,""))
```

Please note that it's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), so needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Nice, I see now.  At first I thought you select B2:B6 and then hit `ctrl+shift+enter` but I see now you just `ctrl+shift+enter` the first cell and fill down.  Cool!  A lot simpler than mine...